# show $[0,1]$ is uncountable using outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a question from *Real Analysis* by Royden, 4th edition. (#5, pg. 34)

Using properties of outer measure, prove that $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

I believe that I am going to have to assume otherwise and use countable subadditivity in some way to produce a contradiction. I am not sure how to do so though. What other properties of outer measure might I need?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you already know points have measure zero?

If so, then enumerate all points in $[0,1]$. The "countable" union of all these points is the entire interval, with measure $1$. The "countable" sum of the measures of all these points, on the other hand, is...

Comment: In any proof of the fact that [0,1] is uncountable, you are bound to use the completeness axiom of the real numbers (after all, it is this completeness axiom that gives birth to the irrationals from the rationals, which previously formed a countable set!). For example, in Cantor's proof, it was used in the fact that every real number has a decimal representation. Hence, in Baron VT's proof also, the completeness axiom is exploited somewhere! Can you figure out, where? These kind of exercises will help you develop your mathematical feelings more and more!

Answer (score 5):

Let [0 1] is countable then outer measure of [0 1] is "zero" because outer measure of countable st is zero . and we also know that outer measure of [a b] is "b-a" so m*[0 1]=1-0=1.
           This is contradiction our assumption so [0 1] is uncountable.

Comment: Well this answer deserves more upvotes. Simple and elegant solution